# Save data if not exist in the model using django and update if the data exists

Tags: javascript, python, html, mysql, django-models

Am using a django framework to build a dashboard.

The code used: **Views.py**

```
def send_data(request):
try:
    conn = connections["default"]
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    user = request.user
    response_dict = {} 
    response_dict = {'status': 0, 'data': []}
    solution_id=request.GET.get('SOLUTION_ID')
    solution_name = request.GET.get('SOLUTION_NAME')
    comments= request.GET.get('COMMENTS')
    try:
        user = SUBMIT()
        user. solution_id = solution_id
        user. solution_name = solution_name
        user.comments = comments
        user.save()
        response_dict["status"] = 1
    except Exception as e:
        response_dict["status"] = 0
        response_dict["exception"] = str(e)
except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_dict))
```

**Models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
class SUBMIT(models.Model):
         solution_id =models.CharField(max_length = 100)
         solution_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
         user.comments = models.CharField(max_length = 1000)
```

The comment field is a textarea in the front end once the comment is entered and saved by the user all the three fields are saved in MySQL database. If the user wants to update the comment second time it is not allowed since solution_id is a primary key in the table. How to update the existing row in the table.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If object is creating, there is no `solution_id` yet in `def send_data()`, right?

So just chek it and then make update or create

```
try:
    if solution_id: # update
        user = SUBMIT.objects.get(solution_id = solution_id)
        user.solution_name = solution_name
        user.comments = comments
        user.save()
    else: # create
        SUBMIT.objects.create(solution_name = solution_name, comments = comments)
    response_dict["status"] = 1
except Exception as e:
    response_dict["status"] = 0
    response_dict["exception"] = str(e)
```

**Update on comment**

if `solution_id` entered by the user

```
try:
    user = SUBMIT.objects.get_or_create(solution_id = solution_id)[0]
    user.solution_name = solution_name
    user.comments = comments
    user.save()
    response_dict["status"] = 1
except Exception as e:
    response_dict["status"] = 0
    response_dict["exception"] = str(e)
```

Comment: The solution id is entered by the user through front end